# All radio buttons are selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i have a problem with my jQuery code and my radio buttons,
if i selected one button and another he stay checked i don't know how to fix that if someone can help me to slove my problem thank you. I leave my code and screenshoot to see what actualy happend.

[image]

```js
$("#custom").click(function() {
  $(".custom").css({
    "display": "block"
  })
})

$("#man").click(function() {
  $(".custom").css({
    "display": "none"
  })
})

$("#ladies").click(function() {
  $(".custom").css({
    "display": "none"
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="ladies" name="ladies" value="ladies">
<label for="ladies">Ladies</label>

<input type="radio" id="man" name="man" value="man">
<label for="man">Man</label>

<input type="radio" id="custom" name="custom" value="custom">
<label for="custom">Custom</label>
<a href="#" class="icons"><i class="fas fa-question-circle fa-1x"></i></a>

<div class="custom">

  <form action="#">
    <select name='gender' id='gender'>
      <option value='gender' disabled>Select the pronoun you are using</option>
      <option value='she'>She: "Wihs her a happy brithday"</option>
      <option value='he'>He: "Wish him a happy birthday!"</option>
      <option value='he/she'>He / She: "Wish him / her a happy birthday!"</option>
    </select>
    <p class="genderTxt">The chosen pronoun is visible to everyone.</p>
    <input type="text" class="optionalG" placeholder="Gender (optional)">
  </form>
</div>
```

I do not have any error message to show up.

Comment: All the radio buttons in a group need to have the same name.

Comment: ah, yes. I am a ladies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name attribute on the group of radio buttons need to have the same name.

Change this:

```
 <input type="radio" id="ladies" name="ladies" value="ladies">
 <label for="ladies">Ladies</label>

 <input type="radio" id="man" name="man" value="man">
 <label for="man">Man</label>

 <input type="radio" id="custom" name="custom" value="custom">
 <label for="custom">Custom</label>
```

To this

```
 <input type="radio" id="ladies" name="radioGroup" value="ladies">
 <label for="ladies">Ladies</label>

 <input type="radio" id="man" name="radioGroup" value="man">
 <label for="man">Man</label>

 <input type="radio" id="custom" name="radioGroup" value="custom">
 <label for="custom">Custom</label>
```

The name doesn't need to be "radioGroup", but it needs to be the same so the code can tell which groups of radio buttons belong together.

Comment: Except that's used for the `<select>` in the form.

Answer (score 2):

All `<input type="radio">` tags need the same `name` attribute. Then it will work.

```html
<input type="radio" id="ladies" name="gender" value="ladies" checked>
<label for="ladies">Ladies</label>

<input type="radio" id="man" name="gender" value="man">
<label for="man">Man</label>

<input type="radio" id="custom" name="gender" value="custom">
<label for="custom">Custom</label>
```

Comment: The option tags only exist in the select tag, not the radio group that the question is referencing.

Comment: Sorry, i meant input tag